# Sipura / Linksys / Cisco SPA3102 problems with analogue phone

Tags: voip, gateway

I have bought 2 of these SPA3102 - One direct from china(verified original) and one from Ebuyer UK but it is called SPA3102 -UK

[I find this guide and followed it](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2008-01-08.php)

I am only going to talk about the one from UK with the -UK suffix. Following the guid BEFORE plugging in any power- When plugged into BT Connect and using a an alaogues phone the internal relay should just let you use the phone direct with BT. But neither phone I use gets any dial tone. (One standard wired and one wireless with powered base station) - Yes they both work in the TEST socket.And the SPA3102 is also plugged into the test socket.

I am using a master socket and I double checked it has a ringer capacitor in the test socket and on the filter socket(but I removed the filter socket to make sure I am directly connected to BT)

OK - The guide says if that doesn't work then I have wiring problems- nothing specific. Sure as anything I could not have plugged the wire into the wrong port- So does he mean BT wiring or what?)

Call CISCO? Yes I did. No help. They keep on going about the device being locked- even though I uploaded it with the cisco. 5.xx unlocked firmware.(and the GUI says "UNLOCKED" - Hinting that is is unlocked! Arrrr - damn the guys was annoying I wanted to ... )

Besides everybody keeps on talking about access the IVR menu and do a reset? How the **** can I do that if no analogue phone gets any dial tone, with it ON or OFF.

I followed the guide to the end. I get 3 lights on, SIP registers, all the regional settings, NTP is set and the time is correct. Just both of the SPA's analogue ports do NOT  work- (plus I bricked the one from eBay cause I forgot enable wan GUI forward and disabled DHCP on LAN - oops- where is the hard reset button? there is none. Great?!)

How can both SPA's not work - Is it possible something wrong with my BT line? (PS I tested the line and it has 50volts as expected and 75volt on ring)(plus I physicall inverted the polarity and rewired on cable to re route the line from the outside pins into the internal one (some times that fixes the issue) Not this time :( )

Any body have any similar story or is my luck Sooooo bad that both devices are knackered?What else can I check?

Anybody that can give me an answer that works I will give you a nice big fat bounty (>= 100) on top of an accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press `**` or `****` and there is nothing, no dialtone, no voice; just dead. Then it is a pin misconfiguration!

SPA3102 uses the inner most 2 pins. This is standard in the USA and is called Modem Pin Configuration in EU

What makes it worse is that in the UK you get the RJ11-UK - Flat plug version and voice uses the outermost pins. The RJ-11 Side is the same. So the wires are mismatched.

---

To solve the problem you need to use `UK to RJ11` from the UK wall socket to the SPA3102. NOtice the pin configuration.

[image]

*You can also use a a standard RJ11-RJ11 from a ADSL filter that is plugged ontop of another ADSL filter. Yes! That will work- Use the MODEM PORT not the UK Line port.*

---

Then from the SPA3102 to the phone you need to use a `RJ11 to BT` converter. Then plug your normal UK phone line into the BT socket and you will hear **THE VOICE**

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem- And the 3 devices that i sent back were working! Lol. I opened a CISCO support ticket and the acknowledged that the documentation is missing this information. 8 Years later!?!?! Anyway the new CD's and online help with cointain this info. Good luck!

Comment: Another important fact which helps with troubleshooting is that if you remove the power from the SPA3102, then a relay closes which links the PSTN and line 1 sockets electrically.  So the right way to sort out the wiring is with the unit de-powered, so that you don't get distracted by any configuration issues.

Comment: Yea - even after I powered it off and I heard the relay click. There was no dial tone.(even though the configuration was OK and SIP was connected during power on) You have to make sure to use the Modem standard cable and bt converter otherwise you will never have dial tone in the UK. Cisco opened a case and updated the documentation (8 years after product release) I am surprised other people found the answer easier than I did, even with 8 hours cisco support and 3 new devices. LOL@CISCO! (PS- I bought the SPA3102-**UK**) What is the point of UK if it did not work LOLx2

Comment: Thanks @ppumkin for a great question and answer with a lot of good information to help those who need it.

Comment: No problem mate. It drove me nuts for weeks... but that is just the  Cisco standard... yuck. But once its configured it works without problem. Yay!

Answer (score -2):

The only way to reset so you can start configuring again it to plug in a telephone (POTS) and lift the handset (whether dial tone or not) and press **** you should hear a voice...

You would want these followed by the HASH (#) key

Factory Reset: - 73738
- 1 to confirm
- * to cancel

User Factory Reset: - 877778
- 1 to confirm
- 0 to cancel

[Reference commands](http://forum.voxilla.com/threads/linksys-atas-ivr-menu-commands-the-admins-handbook.17637/)

I found that setting DHCP, STATIC OR PPOE are sometime different ie selection (1,2,3) so you have to check.
Also make sure that you reset the device after changing the settings as they are not completed until you do.
When resetting it will not reset until the handset line is closed and no communication from a lan cable. Look for no lights then red to be sure.

Otherwise you could say that the device is dead.

Comment: Yes I read that 1 million times from a billion website. But the first time in the manual, the second time from Cisco Support then from all the great forums.. and now you. So annoying. Besides- I said in my OP that DID THAT ALREADY. -1